# Pass argument to custom access callback

Tags: routes, 8

Is there a way to specify an argument to pass to a custom access callback, specifically an argument that isn't part of the path? Like in Drupal 7 you could do this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['abc/$val'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_abcdef_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'test1'),
  );
  $items['def/$val'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_def_view',
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_abcdef_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'test2'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_abc_access($val, $type) {
  return ($val['some_prop'] == $type);
}
```

So in Drupal 8 I would have this in mymodule.routing.yml:

```
mymodule.abc:
  path: 'abc/{val}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::abc'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::abcDefAccess'

mymodule.def:
  path: 'def/{val}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::def'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::abcDefAccess'
```

And in MyModuleController:

```
public function abcDefAccess($val, $type) {
  return AccessResult::allowedIf($val->someProp == $type);
}
```

But is there any way to pass 'test1' or 'test2' as $type? Otherwise I guess I would just have to make a separate access function for each type.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but after reading this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2122195, it seems like you've implemented a "Simplified custom access checker" and that you'd be able to do more complex things if you implement a full custom access check class that extends AccessInterface and use the arguments in the associated service to pass in your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D8 you can use custom route arguments:

> Passing arguments to controllers
>
> All keys under the defaults section which do not start with an
>   underscore will be passed in as arguments to the controller. Name your
>   arguments appropriately for the arguments of the controller. For
>   example a routing.yml file with the following:
>
> ```
> example.content:
>   path: '/example' 
>   defaults: 
>     _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content' 
>     custom_arg: 12
>   requirements: 
>     _permission: 'access content'
> ```
>
> Will pass on $custom_arg to the controller, so your content method can
>   take $custom_arg:
>
> ```
>   public function content(Request $request, $custom_arg) {
>     // Now can use $custom_arg (which will get 12 here) and $request.
>   }
> ```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

While the documentation is for a controller, the same applies to other route callbacks, like in your case an access callback:

```
public function abcDefAccess($val, $custom_arg) {
  return AccessResult::allowedIf($val->someProp == $custom_arg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your route:

```
regportal_user.orders:
  path: '/user/{user}/orders'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'user.orders'
    _title: 'Управление заказами'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\regportal_user\Controller\RegportalUserController::accessOwnOrders'
```

Your controller:

```
  /**
   * Checks access for a regportal_user.orders route.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult
   */
  public function accessOwnOrders(AccountInterface $account, $user) {
    if ($account->id() == $user) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }

    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As @4k4 said, adding a non-underscored default to the route entry will send that exact string as a parameter to the custom access controller, as long as the parameter names match up.  Since your `abcDefAccess` method wants `$type`, just add `type` to your routing definitions.  So mymodule.routing.yml becomes:

```
mymodule.abc:
  path: 'abc/{val}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::abc'
    type: 'abc'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::abcDefAccess'

mymodule.def:
  path: 'def/{val}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::def'
    type: 'def'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::abcDefAccess'
```